# RESTful webservice proxy class

Tags: jaxb, jax-ws, jpa-2.0, jersey, business-objects-sdk

I've written a Jersey-client application that interacts with two web services, one that is REST, the other that is SOAP.  I use the employee data supplied by the REST service to create an new User with the SOAP service.

The REST service is a JAX-RS (Jersey) application that returns an Employee entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "EMPLOYEE_TABLE")
@XmlRootElement
public class Employee implements Serializable {
  ...
}
```

I have not explicitly created a schema definition for the entity class.

A GET request returns a representation of the Employee entity:

```
GET /employees/100

<Employee id='100' providerId='3345'>
  <Link type="application/xml" href="/employees/100" rel="self"/>
  <Name>Doe, Dr. John</Name>
  <Departments>
    <Department id='10'><Name>Emergency Medicine</Name></Department>
    <Department id='56'><Name>Behavioral Medicine</Name></Department>
  </Departments>
</Employee>
```

The SOAP service (BusinessObjects Enterprise web-services SDK) provides a Java client to simplify its usage.

While I could parse the XML-representation of the Employee entity and assign it to the appropriate setters of the User class, it would probably be easier to create an Employee proxy class (with the appropriate annotations) in my Jersey client application.

Questions:

1. Does JAX-RS (specifically Jersey, in my case) have a mechanism to expose an entity's schema definition (XSD format)?  The WADL document doesn't include this type of information.
2. While I could manually create a POJO-class representation that mimics the Employee resource class, I should probably be using a 'tool'.  What are my options for this?
3. As time progresses, I may need to add additional elements to the Employee entity.  Does this mean that a new version of the RESTful services needs to be created?
4. Assuming that Jersey can be configured to automatically generate and expose a schema definition, and that changes to the Employee would then alter the schema definition, should the Employee entity implement an interface to prevent unauthorized changes?

Comment: Concerning points 3 and 4: you have to manage REST API URLs. For example, for initial version you'll have `/myservice/1.0.0/getlist` URL.

Answer (score 0):

Concerning question 1, if your XSD is deployed in your webapp you can just navigate to it in a browser.  For example, in my webapp I have an `/xsd` folder containing my XSD.  When the app is running I can point my browser to `http://localhost:8080/<app_name>/xsd/<xsd_name>.xsd` and see the XSD.

Comment: Yes. But then I use a maven plugin to generate the Java code from the XSD.  It's my understanding that you can go the other way, too.  You can write your Java code and then generate your XSD from that.  Personally I've never done it that way before.

Comment: I was hoping that the implementation (Jersey, in my case) would be able to generate the XSD dynamically, with an option to cache it for better performance.